# Am Telefon verbinden mit, zu, in

Tags: preposition

Sind alle drei Präpositionen korrekt wenn man am Telefon nach Verbindung mit/zu/in eine Abteilung fragt?

> Könnten Sie mich bitte **mit/ in/ zur** Abteilung X verbinden?

Comment: Könnten Sie mich bitte mit/ in/ zur Abteilung X verbinden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Präpositionen unterliegen in längeren Zeiträume sprachlichen Veränderungen in der Anwendung und eine durchgreifende "Normierung" findet sich nicht immer.

Das Buch **Im Bergwerk der Sprache** enthält beispielsweise:

"Der analoge Gebrauch der gleichen Präposition bei Verb, Nomen oder Adjektiv ist nicht in allen Fällen eingerichtet. (mit Beispielen):"

> sich interessieren für, **aber:** interessiert sein an
>
> verbinden mit, **aber:** in enger Verbindung zu
>
> sich auf / über etwas einigen **aber:** sich einig sein in

Für die Bitte um telefonische (Weiter-) Verbindung in eine andere Abteilung sollte `mit` verwendet werden:

> Verbinden Sie mich bitte mit der zuständigen Abteilung für meine Anfrage.

Die genannten Alternativen sind mehr räumlich belegt:

> Begleiten Sie mich bitte zu dem zuständigen Bearbeiter im Gebäude.
>
> Bringen Sie mich bitte in die zuständige Abteilung.